# RestSharp RestClient.Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

Estoy tratando de crear un cliente utilizando la libreria RestSharp consumiendo una API asp .net Core 2.

El método Get se conecta y resuelve todo bien, el problema estoy teniendo con el método POST.

ejemplo utilizando la librería RestSharp

```
public MResult<string[]> ProcessPost(MResult<string[]> data, string format)
{
    var restClient = new RestClient(this.webApiUri.AbsoluteUri);
    var restRequest = new RestRequest("api/JIGMES/ProcessPost", Method.POST);
    restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    restRequest.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var result = restClient.Post(restRequest);

    return null;
}
```

este es el método del API rest

```
    [HttpPost("ProcessPost")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessPost([FromBody]MResult<string[]> data)
    {
        var result = await Task.Run(() => GetTest());
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

El problema que logra detectar es que no llega al Api Rest y no me tira ninguna excepción que puede identificar.

esta es la captura de resultado en el cliente.
[image: valor]

espero que puedan darme una mano para poder orientarme.

saludos

Answer (score 1):

@Richard Víquez Pérez muchas gracias por la ayuda.

al final pude resolverlo de esta forma.

[image: get con data]

method 
[image: request]

para el proyecto que estoy realizando me es suficiente.

igual, muchas gracias

Comment: por favor lee [answer], el código va como texto y no como imagen, por favor edita y corrige, llevas tiempo suficiente en la plataforma para saber que lo que te menciono

Answer (score 0):

No puede pasar el json como lo esta pasando . 
Tiene que pasar el json parecido a el siguiente formato en una cadena:

```
     string cadena="{\n\t\"Codigo\": \"2\",\n    \"Descripcion\": \"coca\",\n   
     \"Precio\":\"11\",\n    \"Cantidad\": \"98\",\n    \"Categoria\": \"bebidas\",\n 
     \"Impuesto\": \"Impuesto\",\n    \"Costo\": \"12345\"\n\t\n}"
```

Lo que podria hacer es hacer la peticion post en postman y agarrandola estructura del json exactamente igual como lo arma postman

Comment: gracias @Richard Viquez Pérez por la respuestos. acabo de probar tu sugerencia pero no tuve exito. este es la conversión que realice.

{\"Mensaje\":\"New\",\"Data\":[\"Data_1\",\"Data_2\",\"Data_3\",\"Data_4\"]}

Comment: no esta bien ese json

Comment: mandeme el json y yo le devuelvo la cadena